# How do you manage Postgresql database connections in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, upsert

I am using Upsert in a Rails app and as a result there are a number of Postgresql connections that I am creating on my own:

```
connection = PG.connect(dbname: db_name)
Upsert.batch(connection, :items) do |upsert|
  ...
end
```

I'm wondering, is there a better way to manage these connections? Do these connections need to be closed in some way?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to close the connection manually. Please check this - https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert

Comment: I have looked at that Upsert gem page but where does it reference closing the connections?